# Как запретить Proguard трогать framework.jar (Java Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Как запретить Proguard трогать framework.jar

Если я включаю Proguard то выпадает ошибка ...

```
08-16 07:32:30.041 6738-6738/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: dima113xxx.coin_calculator, PID: 6738
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method asAttributeSet(Ld/b/a/a;)Landroid/util/AttributeSet; in class Landroid/util/Xml; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.util.Xml' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.o.f()
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.o.a()
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.o.a()
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.o.b()
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.o.a()
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ua.c()
        at androidx.appcompat.app.x.<init>()
        at androidx.appcompat.app.o.a()
        at androidx.appcompat.app.m.g()
        at androidx.appcompat.app.m.onCreate()
        at dima113xxx.coin_calculator.Main2Activity.onCreate()
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: А при каких обстоятельствах он его "трогает"?

Comment: я обновил описание

Comment: Нужно добавить в proguard-rules  следующее  -keep class org.xmlpull.v1.** { *; }  РАБОТАЕТ ДЛЯ МЕНЯ!!